# Python macro works when run by Tools -> Macro... but not when associated to a button (LibreOffice Calc)

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have written this simple macro in Python:

```
#!/bin/python3

#Script usado no programa Form_Atendimento.ods

#Cria objeto document, referenciando o documento aberto
document = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()

#Cria objeto sheets, referenciando as planilhas
sheets = document.getSheets()

#Função que configura os parâmetros para que seja escrita a função =HOJE
def write_today():
    
    information = '=TODAY()'
    sheet = 'Form'
    location = 'B5'
    write_function(information, sheet, location)
    
    return 0

#Função que escreve qualquer função
def write_function(information, sheet, location):

    sheetForm = sheets.getByName(sheet)
    sheetForm.getCellRangeByName(location).setFormula(information)
        
    return 0
```

When I execute it by Tools -> Macros -> Execute Macro, it **works**.
But I associate it with a "press button" in my spreadsheet, and when I press the button, it shows the following **error**:

> com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException: Error during invoking function
> write_today in module
> file:///C:/Users/34471945882/AppData/Roaming/LibreOffice/4/user/Scripts/python/data_hoje.py
> (<class 'TypeError'>: write_today() takes 0 positional arguments but 1
> was given File "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\pythonscript.py",
> line 915, in invoke ret = self.func(*args))

LibreOffice Version: Version: 7.1.4.2 (x64) / LibreOffice Community

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try `def write_today(oEvent):` or any other dummy param. When you click the button, it tries to tell the macro about itself, about the caller. This function needs a parameter (even if you don't use it)

Comment: Hi @JohnSUN, thank you again. Now it is working with the button. It was what I needed.

Just a information for future readers: when you apply that solution, the macro doesn't work by 'Tools way' anymore.

Comment: Try to learn more about optional parameters of functions and use something like `(oEvent=None)`